# NSMutableArray leaks

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying the create a NSMutableArray by reading the contents of a file.

```
NSString *filePath = FILE_PATH;

NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    ...

   [tempArr release];
```

But i am getting memory leaks in the line where i am allocating the array.

What is the bug in the code ?

Thanks

Comment: probably the bag is where you put ellipsis?...

Comment: Please provide the code where ... stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vladimir said the problem is between those lines. Leaks showing the leak where the variable was created. But in fact you're over-retaining that array somewhere. double check your code.